# iOS Login Modal

Tags: ios, core-data, authentication

I'm writing an iOS application which I need to have the user login to. The login will need to make a JSON request to a web service, then store the user details in Core Data or wherever is best.

Further, I need to have the login modal appear before the main application kicks in, I know that for this I call it in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

So, I need a simple login, username and password field, make a request and then store the resulting JSON data into somewhere, core data perhaps?

I've searched high and low for a login example, but they're all very rudimentary or not doing quite what I want. I'm thinking of creating a xib file then calling that, but I'm unsure about it all.

Comment: You may want to try [AuthNavigation](https://github.com/columbbus/AuthNavigation) framework. It basically gives you the structure you need for a login screen (and loading screen, which helps you to make your JSON request in the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same question several days ago.
Here is my solution:
in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ,I invoke a method check whether there is account and password in your database(core data? i just use the userdefault).
If there is , try login, if login fail, present a modal view. if successed, set your appdelegate.window.rootviewcontroller the main viewcontroller
If there is nothing, show modal view.

or login failed, blablabla...

sorry for my poor English.
here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [ZTCAPIClient registerUserInfo];
    return YES;
}

+ (void) registerUserInfo {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *account = [defaults stringForKey:@"account"];
if(!account) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // load default value
        [self performSelector:@selector(registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle)];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ZTCUserSettingsViewController *userSettingsView = [[ZTCUserSettingsViewController alloc] init];
            UINavigationController *usersSettingsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userSettingsView];
            [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:usersSettingsNav animated:NO];
            [ZTCNotice showSuccessNoticeInView:userSettingsView.view title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",NSLocalizedString(@"login first time use title", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"login first time use message", nil)]];//TODO
        });
    });
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if ([ZTCAPIClient loginWithAccount:[defaults stringForKey:@"account"] Password:[defaults stringForKey:@"password"] BaseURL:[defaults stringForKey:@"url"]]) {
            //DLog(@"Log in SUCCESS");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UITableViewController *viewController = [[ZTCTaskListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
                UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
                [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:nav];
            });
        } else {
            //DLog(@"Log in FAIL");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                ZTCUserSettingsViewController *userSettingsView = [[ZTCUserSettingsViewController alloc] init];
                UINavigationController *usersSettingsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userSettingsView];
                [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:usersSettingsNav animated:NO];
                [ZTCNotice showErrorNoticeInView:userSettingsView.view title:NSLocalizedString(@"login fail title", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"login fail message", nil)];
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: oh, my first best answer! Thank you too! @James

Comment: And anyone vote down, just let me know why, I just try to help like others helped me

Answer (score 1):

Just make `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` modally push your `LoginViewController` to the navigation stack. If you're using a storyboard, you can just make your `LoginViewController` the root view controller, or alternatively place a segue, give it an identifier, and just call `[rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueId" sender:self]`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. And what would be the best practise for storing login data?

Comment: Glad I could help. Always store sensitive informations in the keychain.

Comment: Absolutely, I didn't know about the keychain, I just thought "Core data" heh. Thanks!